# How to get sum of amount from multiple accounts which return by join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like:

owner_details:-

```
 owner_id   owner_name
    ---------------------
    1            A
    2            B    
    3            C
    -------------------
```

vehicle_owner:-

```
    v_id  vehicle_id   owner_id
    -------------------------
    1      1            1
    2      2            2
    3      4            1
    4      3            1 
    5      5            3
```

transaction:-

```
id   v_id         amount   transaction_type
--------------------------------
1      1           100       0
2      2           250       1
3      1           150       1
4      3           450       1
5      1           200       0
6      4           300       1
7      5           150       0
8      5           200       1
```

transaction_type= 0 then (-) transaction_type=1 then (+)

Owner A (1) have 3 vehicles with **v_id** (1,3,4) in table ***vehicle_owner***.

**v_id** (1,3,4) have 5 entries in table ***transaction*** (1,3,4,5,6) with sum of amount 600 (-100+150+450-200+300)

Now I want listing like this:-.

```
owner_id   owner_name  amount
    ---------------------
    1            A       600
    2            B       250
    3            C       50
    -------------------
```

Comment: You tried anything? Seems like simple select, sum, join, group by ... come on ... put some effort into this stuff ...

Comment: Actualy it's part of query .Main query have multiple  JOIN of another tables which work fine.Now I want show total amout of perticular owner in list

Comment: `amount` of A should be 1200. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT od.owner_id, od.owner_name, SUM(t.amount) AS amount 
FROM owner_details od INNER JOIN vehicle_owner vo ON od.owner_id = vo.owner_id 
    INNER JOIN `transaction` t ON vo.v_id = t.v_id 
GROUP BY od.owner_id
```

---

If you want to use the additional `transaction_type` you can use the following:

```
SELECT od.owner_id, od.owner_name, SUM(CASE WHEN t.transaction_type = 0 THEN t.amount * -1 ELSE t.amount END) AS amount 
FROM owner_details od INNER JOIN vehicle_owner vo ON od.owner_id = vo.owner_id 
    INNER JOIN `transaction` t ON vo.v_id = t.v_id 
GROUP BY od.owner_id
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5f8d/1/1

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Brosch for answer.But if I have extra column in table transaction say transaction_type which stored 0 or 1 (0-debit,1-credit) then what will be change in query?

Comment: No, in case you don't want to show this column on the result of the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.owner_id, A.owner_name, SUM(IFNULL(amount,0)) AMOUNT
FROM owner_details A LEFT JOIN
vehicle_owner B
ON A.owner_id=B.owner_id
LEFT JOIN `transaction` C
ON C.v_id=B.v_id
GROUP BY A.owner_id, A.owner_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
SELECT od.owner_id, 
           od.owner_name, 
           Sum(t.amount) AS amount 
    FROM   owner_details od 
           INNER JOIN vehicle_owner vo 
                   ON od.owner_id = vo.owner_id 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT v_id, 
                              Coalesce(Sum(CASE 
                                             WHEN type = 0 THEN -amount 
                                             ELSE +amount 
                                           end), 0.0) AS amount 
                       FROM   `transaction` 
                       GROUP  BY v_id) t 
                   ON vo.v_id = t.v_id 
    GROUP  BY od.owner_id
```

Thanks  **Sebastian Brosch** for quick response !!!